# Getting error on executing put-object-tagging example from aws documentation

Tags: amazon-web-services, cmd, aws-cli, windows-11

I am trying to execute the following example from https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/put-object-tagging.html on Windows-11 cmd

```
aws s3api put-object-tagging --bucket my-bucket --key doc1.rtf --tagging '{"TagSet": [{ "Key": "designation", "Value": "confidential" }]}'
```

but it throws this error:

```
usage: aws [options] <command> <subcommand> [<subcommand> ...] [parameters]
To see help text, you can run:

  aws help
  aws <command> help
  aws <command> <subcommand> help

Unknown options: Key:, designation,, Value:, confidential, }]}', [{
```

I have changed the bucket name and object name in the command. The CLI user also has the right permission.

I also tried the following way:

```
aws s3api put-object-tagging --bucket my-bucket --key doc1.rtf --tagging 'TagSet=[{Key=designation,Value=confidential}]'
```

which resulted in a different error:

```
Error parsing parameter '--tagging': Expected: '=', received: ''' for input:
'TagSet={Key=designation,Value=confidential}'
^
```

Comment: Have you tried changing your single quote characters, `'` to double quote characters, `"`?

Comment: @Compo, Thanks for the suggestion. I just tried my command (the second one in the question) with double quotes and indeed it works. If you post it as an answer, I will accept it. If not, please let me know and I will just add it to my existing answer so that the answer can be more useful to future visitors.

Comment: For your first command example, did you try escaping the nested double quote characters, ```..."{\"TagSet\": [{ \"Key\": \"designation\", \"Value\": \"confidential\" }]}"```?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried the following command with Windows Powershell and it worked without any problem.

```
aws s3api put-object-tagging --bucket my-bucket --key OSI-Model.png --tagging 'TagSet=[{Key=DataSecurity,Value=Confidential},{Key=Department,Value=HR},{Key=TagBy,Value=Bob}]'
```

So, one solution is to use Powershell instead of cmd.

I will try to find a solution for Windows cmd and update this answer if I successfully execute it with cmd.

## Update

I found the solution to execute it with Windows cmd. The solution was to remove single quotes from my command e.g. the following command runs successfully with Windows cmd.

```
aws s3api put-object-tagging --bucket my-bucket --key OSI-Model.png --tagging TagSet=[{Key=DataSecurity,Value=Confidential},{Key=Department,Value=HR},{Key=TagBy,Value=Bob}]
```

However, without quotes, this solution fails if there is whitespace inside `TagSet` e.g. the following command fails:

```
aws s3api put-object-tagging --bucket my-bucket --key OSI-Model.png --tagging TagSet=[{Key=DataSecurity,Value=Confidential}, {Key=Department,Value=HR}, {Key=TagBy,Value=Bob}]
```

The best solution was provided by the user, [Compo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6738015/compo) and the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76401386/getting-error-on-executing-put-object-tagging-example-from-aws-documentation#comment134722235_76401386) was to use double quotes e.g. the following command runs successfully with Windows cmd:

```
aws s3api put-object-tagging --bucket my-bucket --key OSI-Model.png --tagging "TagSet=[{Key=DataSecurity,Value=Confidential}, {Key=Department,Value=HR}, {Key=TagBy,Value=Bob}]"
```